# Entity Model + Scalar Property + Custom Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When using entity framework's model designer is it possible to add a property to an entity that is not one of the standard types?

I have these two entities. The one, VirusDescription I would like to add another property which is a class I wrote however when you go to change the type of the property it only gives you basics... i.e. strings, int16...etc. Is there a way to include custom types in the designer?
[image]

I can go into the code that the designer generates and just add it myself and everything works fine but I would like the code and the designer to be consistent.

Here is the class definition for the VirusDescription entity which I updated by hand. If there is a way to update the designer from the corresponding code that would work too.

```
namespace Trojan.Database
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class VirusDescriptionItems
    {
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string VirusId { get; set; }
        public bool On_Off { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public short AttributeId { get; set; }
        public short CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; } //Added
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; } //Added
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a complex type within the entity model browser and extend the generated class using partial implementations.